# How to make a txt/doc/pdf/html file as we want to view in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have the tables and data .

What i want is, to generate a report of all the students **`sorted`** by there `names`..

```
--student table

create table student(
sid int,
sname text
);


--student details

insert into student(sid,sname)
values(101,'John'),
(102,'barbie'),
(103,'britney'),
(104,'jackson'),
(105,'abraham')
;

--questions table all the questions for the test

create table questions(
questionid serial,
question text
);

--i have the questions in my table 

insert into questions(question)
values('How much is 1+1'),('What is the value of PI'),('Whose dimensions are all equal');

--the test table it contains the details of the test attebdee by every student..

create table test(
sno serial,
sid int,
questionid int,
answer text,
marks int  
);

--insert into test table the answers and the marks ..should be updated here..

insert into test(sid,questionid,answer,marks)
values(101,1,'2',10),
(102,2,' 3 ',0),
(103,3,' ring ',0),
(104,1,' 1 ',0),
(105,1,' 1 ',0),
(101,2,'3.7',0),
(101,3,' square',10);
```

My Requirement:

My txt/doc/pdf/html  file which is generated should be in a view as below

[image]

[**<kbd>live sql fiddle demo i tried</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1f03a/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be something like this:

```
copy(
    with cte as (
        select
            s.sid, s.sname,
            q.question, t.answer, t.marks,
            row_number() over(partition by s.sid order by t.sno) as row_num
        from student as s
            left outer join test as t on t.sid = s.sid
            left outer join questions as q on q.questionid = t.questionid
    )
    select
        case when c.row_num = 1 then c.sid else null end as sid,
        case when c.row_num = 1 then c.sname else null end as sname,
        c.question, c.answer, c.marks
        from cte as c
        order by c.sname asc, c.row_num asc
) to 'e:\sample.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1f03a/11)

Comment: how can i create a text file from this..i am aware of creating a text file from table by using:: copy table_name to 'e:\sample.csv' delimiters ',' csv header;

Comment: but i dont want to waste excess space by creating a new table

Comment: `copy (
with cte as (
    select
        s.sid, s.sname,
        q.question, t.answer, t.marks,
        row_number() over(partition by s.sid order by t.sno) as row_num
    from student as s
        left outer join test as t on t.sid = s.sid
        left outer join questions as q on q.questionid = t.questionid
)
select
    case when c.row_num = 1 then c.sid else null end as sid,
    case when c.row_num = 1 then c.sname else null end as sname,
    c.question, c.answer, c.marks
from cte as c
order by c.sname asc, c.row_num asc
 ) to 'e:\sample.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;`